# How can I make my pyinstaller .exe works?

Tags: keyboard, pyinstaller

I'm trying to run an .exe file that I generated with PyInstaller, but it is not working.

The Python script that I converted is:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.remap_key('n', 'm')
keyboard.remap_key('m', 'n')
```

However, when I run the .exe file, the keys aren't remapped. I even tried running the .exe file with the Command Prompt, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Does this code do what you want when you run it in Python (not via PyInstaller)?